# How to collect defined items in lists python

Tags: python, list, unicode, collect

I have to find the signs "a..,z", "A,..,Z", "space", "." and "," in some data.

I have tried the code:

```
fh = codecs.open("mydata.txt", encoding = "utf-8")
text = fh.read()
fh1 = unicode(text)
dic_freq_signs = dict(Counter(fh1.split()))
All_freq_signs = dic_freq_signs.items()
List_signs = dic_freq_signs.keys()
List_freq_signs = dic_freq_signs.values()
```

BUT it gets me ALL signs not the ones i am looking for? 
Can anyone help?

(And it has to be unicode)

Comment: where do you check for the signs ?

Answer (score 0):

check dictionary iteration ..

```
All_freq_signs = [ item for item in dic_freq_signs.items() if item.something == "somevalue"]
def criteria(value):
    return value%2 == 0
All_freq_signs = [ item for item in dic_freq_signs.items() if criteria(item)]
```

Comment: item.something? :-)

what do you mean?

Comment: import re

    Splitlist = re.split(r'[ ]', "hello you")

    print Splitlist

Comment: you can use any of the two forms  All_freq_signs = [ item for item in dic_freq_signs.items() if item.something == "somevalue"]   or to use some function instead of matching with attributes.

Comment: `>>> Splitlist = [ item for item in re.split(r'[ ]', "hello you") if len(item) > 3]
    >>> print Splitlist
    ['hello']
>>>`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import string module, with it you can get character ranges `a to z` and `A to Z` easily

```
import string
```

A `Counter(any_string)` gives the count of each character in the string. By using `split()` the counter would return the counts of each word in the string, contradicting with your requirement. So I have assumed that you need character counts.

```
dic_all_chars = dict(Counter(fh1))    # this gives counts of all characters in the string
signs = string.lowercase + string.uppercase + ' .,'    # these are the characters you want to check

# using dict comprehension and checking if the key is in the characters you want
dic_freq_signs = {key: value for key, value in dic_all_chars.items() 
                             if key in signs}
```

`dic_freq_signs` would only have the signs that you want to count as keys and their counts as values.